# Crash in msvcp90d.dll when retrieving an iterator from a boost::tokenizer

Tags: c++, stl, crash, iterator, compiler-flags

When I retrieve the begin() iterator of a boost::tokenizer, I get a crash in msvcp90d.dll, that says "ITERATOR LIST CORRUPTED", which looks suspiciously like issues I have run into before with the _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING compiler flag, however I have verified that my program is being compiled with this flag turned off.

Here is the program:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string data("gobo;wimbley;red;moki;boober");
    std::ostringstream input;
    input << data;


    std::string mystr(input.str());
    boost::char_separator<char> separator(";");
    boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tok(mystr, separator);
    boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>>::iterator iter = tok.begin();
}
```

Interestingly, if I replace the instantiation of the tokenizer with the following line, it works:

```
    boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>> tok(data, separator);
```

So it appears to be something related to the ostringstream. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code snippet works fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a bug in Visual C++](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=435483#details) with `std::ostringstream` when `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` is disabled.

If I recall correctly, the `std::string` copy constructor copies iterators.  You can get around this by using the `std::string` conversion constructor taking a `char*` instead.

If you change

```
std::string mystr(input.str());
```

to

```
std::string mystr(input.str().c_str());
```

then no exception is thrown.